# Setting non-native resolution on laptop with FullHD screen

Tags: laptop, display, resolution

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 700-15ISK laptop running Windows 10 with latest drivers for GTX950M installed from NVIDIA's site. Its native resolution is 1080p and as I understood from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/940821/non-native-resolution-is-blurry-on-laptop) the only way to avoid blurring and distortion is to keep that resolution.
But I wanted to set it to 1366x768 in order to see text more clearly. What I tried was to set the DPI scale to 138% - this was the closest I could get to my target resolution. However not everything was scaled fine enough for me - for example, the title of author/song in Winamp was way too small (I had my older Acer Aspire 5738ZG as a comparisson, its native res is 1366x768), also some parts of Adobe Reader had really small text, on the other hand the text in Visual Studio 2015's text editor appeared bigger than usual (really strange).

And my question - is there a way  to **really** simulate 1366x768 on that display (by really I mean exactly how it would display on the Acer where it's a native res)?

Comment: The short answer is no. The scaling is 32/45, or a fraction over 0.7, so a single-pixel line needs to map to ~1.4 pixels, which arbitrarily map to 1 or 2 pixels at different points in the display. Remember that this is being done on the graphics card. Large fonts will scale reasonably well, but small fonts necessarily look dreadful. A smaller resolution will display reasonably if you use a submultiple, eg 1/2 (960x540) displays 2 pixels for each one output. You will always get the clearest display with native resolution. To improve legibility, increase your font sizes, or use a magnifier app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I suspected that would be the case. :)